# HP DL140 Lights-Out licensing issue

Tags: hp, remote

I have two HP DL140 and I recently upgraded their lo firmware. But one of them does accept the license but does not turn virtual kvm on. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Even the most recent DL140, the G3 version, was end-of-sale'd SIX years ago - I'm not sure why you're still using such an old machine and why you'd only now be putting iLO keys onto them but they've gone end-of-support with HP so even they won't help you. Are you sure both licenses are HP P/N: 413115-xxx?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update the firmware of your LO100i IPMI module via USB in order to use the virtual KVM and virtual media on a modern web browser... Are you certain that both servers are up-to-date?

The software and all updates are available from: http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/remotemgmt/lightsout100i-advanced/index.html

Comment: Problem is virtual media/kvm link is compelety not displaying on left vertical menu so not enabled. I already upgraded LO firmware.

Comment: @OzgurErdogan Please try a different web browser or delete your browser cache.